# web crawling in a multi threaded console app

Tags: c#, multithreading, .net-4.0, console-application

New to multi-threded apps.

I am trying to create a console app to check a given list of IP addresses (intranet). Each web page for any given IP address contains some stats, displayed in an html table, that I need to collect.
I can do this in a single thread: set up the request/response sequence, get the page content and parse it.

What I am struggling with right now is to make this multi-threaded since I have to deal with 4000 IP addresses and single thread would take some time. I have the list of IPs in a list or array of strings; do you know how I can set up the threads?

Assuming I have a function that processes the response, say, "ProcessResponse(string s)", and want to start with 10 threads, can I start with something like:

```
public class PASSServer
{
    private string _ip;
    public string IPAddress
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public PASSServer()
    {
    }
}
static void Main(string[] args)
{
        int iNumThreads = 3;
        Thread[] threads = new Thread[iNumThreads];

        string[] sIPs = { "192.168.10.20", "192.168.10.21", "192.168.10.22" };

        for (int i = 0; i < threads.Length; i++)
        {
            ParameterizedThreadStart start = new ParameterizedThreadStart(Start);
            threads[i] = new Thread(start);
            PASSServer pserver = new PASSServer();
            pserver.IPAddress = sIPs[i];
            threads[i].Start(pserver);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("DONE");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
    static void Start(object info)
    {
        PASSServer pserver = (PASSServer)info;
        crawl(pserver.IPAddress);
    }
    private static void crawl(string sUrl)
    {
        PASSData cData = new PASSData();
        string sRequestUrl = "http://" + sUrl.Trim() + "/cgi-bin/sysstat?";
        string sEncodingType = "utf-8";
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(sRequestUrl);
        request.KeepAlive = true;
        request.Timeout = 15 * 1000;

        System.Net.HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
        string sStatus = ((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription;
        sEncodingType = GetEncodingType(response);
        System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.GetEncoding(sEncodingType));

        // Read the content.
        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
        Console.WriteLine(responseFromServer);
    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

I have not used multi threading but googled the subject and got some ideas just not sure how best to set up my scenario.

Comment: Create a thread template to do what you want (in a class) and then kick off those threads with upper/lower bounds of an IP range, so for example thread 1 might look at ip's in range 10.192.168.001 - 10.192.168.100 and then thread 2 might look at .101-.200 and so on... This is really about you making a program, not multithreading. Once you have a multithreaded code, and it's not working anymore, then you have a multithreaded question. But to design it for you is....

Comment: Thanks alykins. I was not asking for code just a high level how-to of setting up the 10 threads, using first 10 IP addresses and then continue until all 4000 are dealt with.

Comment: So take your IP range, and decide what 10 ranges you want the ten threads hitting. In your thread class make a parameter-ized start and then pass those boundaries to each thread to kick it off. Then save data accordingly.

Comment: I update the post with the new code I am using for testing; setting the number of threads to three and using three IP addresses. When I run this, it only displays the content from one IP address.

Comment: it seems it displays 1 response and then times out in GetResponse(). I tried different IP addresses thinking some of the servers might be unresponsive but it is the same result.

Comment: Don't use static voids without locking on an object. That static method is the same for all instances of that class (and in turn all the threads)- if you are going to use the static voids, make a static readonly object and lock on it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use threads. Use asynchronous HTTP requests. For example, use [HttpWebRequest.BeginGetResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetresponse.aspx) or perhaps [HttpWebRequest.GetResponseAsync](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest.getresponseasync.aspx). Limit the number of concurrent requests using a [Semaphore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore(v=vs.110).aspx).

So, if you have a list of URLs (a `List<string>`) and you want a maximum of 10 concurrent requests:

```
List<string> _urls = GetListOfUrls();
Semaphore _requestSemaphore = new Semaphore(10, 10);

foreach (var url in _urls)
{
    // wait for an available spot
    _requestSemaphore.WaitOne();
    // Now start an asynchronous request with this url
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.BeginGetResponse(GetResponseCallback, request);
}
```

When your list is empty, you have to wait for the final responses to be received. The way you do that is to wait on the semaphore 10 times. When you've got 10, then there can't be any outstanding requests:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    _requestSemaphore.WaitOne();
}
```

And your callback, which is called when a response is received:

```
void GetResponseCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    var request = (HttpWebRequest)ar.AsyncState;
    var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.EndGetResponse(ar);
    // process the response here.
    // when you're done processing the response, release the semaphore
    _requestSemaphore.Release();
}
```

Comment: Thank you Jim, works great. I added a ping test in the first foraech loop and get the semaphore if ping test passed. It seems to work (I added an IP to the list I knew would time out). Does this seem OK to you?

Comment: @NoBullMan: I'm not clear on why you'd do a ping and then do the HTTP request. You might find that some sites don't respond to ping requests, but they do fine with HTTP requests. And a successful ping doesn't necessarily mean that the HTTP request will succeed.

Comment: I am trying to see if server is online and can respond to requests. Can I just blindly send requests to all IP addresses in the list and wait for timeout to see if some don't respond? I need to collect that information as well (servers not responding).

Comment: @NoBullMan: As I said, ping won't tell you if the HTTP server is online. So just handle the timeout or other errors when you make the HTTP request. And if my answer solved your problem, please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

I would loop through your list of IP addresses and start a ThreadPool work item.

```
foreach(string addr in IpAddresses)
   Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(
      (string ipaddr) => 
      { 
            ResponseFromQuery resp = new ResponseFromQuery(); 
            this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() => { UpdateTable(resp); }));
      }, addr);
```

*EDIT: Above, you will need to call BeginInvoke and create a methodinvoker that calls back to a new method in your application call UpdateTable. You can pass in your response information (whatever type it is, I used a made up ResponseFromQuery class for example).

You can use either an anonymous function or, if there is a lot of code and you might use it elsewhere, you could create a processing class and method that you can pass as your method that you want executed.

If you wanted to manage your threads yourself, you can create a Dictionary or List object and add a thread to that for each item in your collection:

```
Dictionary<string, Thread> _threads = new Dictionary<string, Thread>();

foreach (string addr in IpAddresses)
{
    _threads.Add(addr, new System.Threading.Thread(
        new System.Threading.ParameterizedThreadStart(
            (object ip) =>
            {
                // process ip. 
            }, addr)));
    _threads[addr].Start();
}
```

Comment: Thank you gmiley. Does this start a thread for each IP address it reads from the list? If so, how would I limit the number of threads to X?

Comment: Yes, it would start one for each IP. If you use the first method, the Thread will be queued in the system, and start when there is a free thread in the pool. The second method you would probably want to write some thread management. Overall, the first method is probably the best if your processing is straight forward, you can queue up threads and forget about them.

Comment: I started with three IPs and after sending request and getting response, I try to display the response (html table with some data in it) but it only displays one table and not three.

Comment: I updated the first method with some more information. See the EDIT.

Comment: What is "this" referring to in "this.BeginInvoke()"? This is a console application not Windows; it seems MethodInvoker is part of System.Windows.Forms.

Comment: The parent class, normally your Form or Page object.